# C# form, how can I to solve my EventHandler problem?

Tags: c#, forms, events, datagridview, timer

I am doing a C# form application, I use a timer and every 10 seconds I have to refresh a datagridview with the elements of a list of list (it may happens that some elements of this list can be removed or others added from another function), in each row of this DataGridView I have to add a  `CellClick` event, the problem is that after each update I add an eventHandler to each row and therefore there are multiple eventListener on every row. When the timer runs out I called the following function:

```
private void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             tabUsers.Rows.Clear();
             tabUsers.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
             for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++){
                 tabUsers.CellClick += grd_CellClick;
                 tabUsers.Rows.Add(list1[i][0], list1[i][1], list1[i][2])
             } 
        }
```

`grd_CellClick` is the event funcion .

Comment: Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The event ist for the grid not for a row, a column or a cell. The info what cell was hit is in the arguments of the event. So simply add the event once and don't fiddle with it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can remove an event handler as follows:

```
tabUsers.CellClick -= grd_CellClick;
```

However, in your case the event handler does not act on the row or cell. It's attached to the gridview control (`tabUsers`).

You are currently attaching `grd_CellClick` as an event handler to the gridview on every refresh and for every row. This is not jsut unnecessary, it's wrong.

Instead, just should configure this event handler once (in the constructor of your form).

Comment: There is no way to remove `grd_CellClick` before attaching the new one?

Comment: I updated my answer. In general, you can remove an event handler using `-=` syntax. But you don't need that in this case.